# Can you set up segfault logging in Centos7?

Tags: linux, centos, logs, segmentation-fault

I have a problem that one of my PHP CLI scripts mysteriously stops running after several hours of uptime. There's no trace in any logfiles, nothing. It seems to just suddenly terminate for no obvious reason. At this point my best guess is that it segfaults, but I don't have any proof of that. Is it possible to set up some sort of segfault logging in the OS so that I could either confirm or disprove this hypothesis? Bonus points if it produces something useful for locating the problem like a stack trace.

The system is Centos 7. PHP version is 7.3.12.

Comment: How is the PHP command launched?

Comment: @jsbillings Cron, why? Oh... hmm... I'll see if Cron has any such features.

Comment: Any output of cron jobs are sent in an email, check the mail spools if you don’t have it forwarded elsewhere.  You might benefit from running them as a real systemd service, because it captures stdout, stderr, syslog, etc. to the journal, and it has ways to handle the service exiting abnormally.

Comment: @jsbillings - Yeah, I've been wanting to move it to systemd for a while now, but we've just never had the time for that.